# Change view of item in Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have an Adapter of products for a market place. I set this adapter with all the products received from the server. I also do a call to the server to get the favorite products of this user because I want to display them with the red heart visible to distinguish them from the rest. I face these two problems:

1. If I set the adapter with all the products and later I modify the items that need to have the red heart active by iterating the list, the user will notice it, even if it is just for 1 second.
2. Having the list of favorite products, how could I modify the view of those favorites?

I am sure there is a simple way to do this.

Thank you

Comment: first get products list and then get favourite list.then loop through products list and compare with favourites list and set a lag for favourite items.then pass the list finally to the adapter.depending on the flag set the red heart insode `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: But I want to display all the products, not only the favorite products. I don't get what you want me to set to the adapter. Products don't have a attribute "favorite", so I can't check it onBindViewHolder.

Comment: Does this products list contains favourite items also?

Comment: Yes, It does, but I don't get how to check onBindViewHolder if the product is a fav or not. I can't add an attribute to Product entity because it does not belong there.

Comment: then pass both lists to adapter.inside onBindViewHolder get each product item and check whether that product is included in favourite list

Comment: it is what I did at the end, save the list of products and the list of those products that are favorite in the adapter.

Comment: But if you can change the backend api as described in following answer by @Learnaholic, that will be more effective.

Answer (score 0):

you need to manipulate the data during the network call to set all the products that have favorites or not, once this is set, just populate the model. it should change the view.

That means before setting the adapter, make all the server calls that need to be mad and manipulate the data.

my advise would be to change the server side code to add a Boolean to each product
of the products list whether it is user favorited or not. This would make your job much easier and avoid making two network calls.

Comment: But each user has a list of favorite products, so the relation is many to many between users and products. How would I add a boolean to the json then?

Comment: okay so that means you must have the user has to sign in to the app and get the list of products to set favorites right ?
just simply pass the user id to the server and get all the products for the user including his favorites

Answer (score 0):

Modify your server code, add a Boolean flag that indicates if a particular product is favorited or not, then populate the view with the data you have(please do this before the views become visible, preferably inside onBindViewHolder). You shouldn't try to manipulate views when they're visible unless the user deliberately triggers the actions by themselves.